# Looking for a better performant String replace solution in Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures, replace

Given a String input which can have only alphabets. The string should be transformed if there is a combination of AB, CD, BA, DC by removing these occurrences and return the resultant String.
example:

1. Input : ABDCC -> Output: C
2. Input : CABABD -> CABD -> CD -> Output: empty string
   I came up with a below solution using String replace function, but looking for a more performant or alternate solution. Any ideas?

```
public String transformString(String s) {
        HashSet<String> stringsToRemove = new HashSet();
        stringsToRemove.add("AB");
        stringsToRemove.add("BA");
        stringsToRemove.add("CD");
        stringsToRemove.add("DC");
        
        int prevLength = -1;
        while (prevLength != s.length()) {
            prevLength = s.length();
            for (String d : stringsToRemove) {
               s = s.replace(d, "");
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: The problem may be harder than you think. For example, consider that the strings to remove are AB and BC, and the input is ABCB. Your code will remove the AB leaving CB. An alternative answer is to remove the BC first, leaving AB, and then remove the AB leaving an empty string.

Comment: `Any ideas?` Sure. Compare to using `StringBuilder`. Either one in addition to the parameter, or two `StringBuilder`s, or process from end to start. With four fixed two-character patterns to delete, compare to using regex and an open coded finite automaton.

Answer (score 1):

Take a strategy from parenthesis matching and use a stack. Solution sketch to get you started:

```
Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
  if (stack.empty()) {
    stack.push(c);
  }
  else {
    char t = stack.peek();
    if (/* t and c match, such as 'A' and 'B' */) {
      stack.pop();
    }
    else {
      stack.push(c);
    }
  }
}

// Return a string based on what's left in the stack.
```

Obviously this works only if "matching" has no edge cases, such as the case user3386109 alluded to in their comment.

This only passes over the input twice (once in the loop, once to unwind the stack to build the output) so is linear time in the size of the input.

Comment: So this solution only works for exactly 2 characters to remove at once, right?

Answer (score 0):

A basic recursive approach (not optimized):

```
public static Set<String> replacements = Set.of("AB", "BA", "CD", "DC");
public String minLenStr(String a, String b){
    if (a.length() <= b.length()){
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}
public String reduceStringUtil(String str, String curMin){
    System.out.println("reduceString(%s, %s)".formatted(str, curMin));
    if (str.length() == 0 || curMin.length() == 0){
        return "";
    }
    for (String rep : replacements){
        String newStr = str.replace(rep, "");
        if (!str.equals(newStr)){
            String newStr2 = reduceStringUtil(newStr, curMin);
            curMin = minLenStr(newStr, newStr2);
        }
    }
    return curMin;
}

public String reduceString(String str){
    return reduceStringUtil(str, str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried my own implementation based on a `StringBuilder` and I also compared it to the recursive and the stack implementation already posted here.

```java
public String removeAll(String original, Set<String> removals) {
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(original);
  int resultLength = result.length();
  int oldLength = 0;
  do {
    for(String remove : removals) {
      int position = 0;
      while(position >= 0) {
        position = result.indexOf(remove, position);
        if(position >= 0) {
          result.delete(position, position + remove.length());
        }
      }
    }
    oldLength = resultLength;
    resultLength = result.length();
  } while ((resultLength > 0) && (resultLength < oldLength));
  return result.toString();
}
```

I tested it with 1000 strings of length 100, created randomly from `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'` and `'D'` (same 1000 strings for all algorithms in one comparison run of course).

- The algorithm I posted above takes ~ 50% the time of your original one.
- The recursion based algorithm is super-dependent on the length of the input (tried to test with 100 strings of length 1000 but had to kill it as I didn't want to wait for minutes for the result of just this implementation), for the configuration described here it takes ~ 7500% of time of the original implementation.
- The stack based algorithm could be wrong - for the two testcases specified in the question it got the same results, but for my random inputs it *did not give the same results as the original algorithm*. Also it the time it takes is very dependent on the input, from 50% to 200% of the time of the original algorithm, but on average it takes longer than the original. (For optimization I replaced the synchronized `Stack` with an unsynchronized `Deque` and tried several implementations of that interface, `ArrayDeque` seems to be the fastest for this algorithm.)

Maybe I made some mistakes on implementing the stack based algorithm as @Welbog did not give the full implementation. I post my implementation here for comparison, please give feedback if you spot mistakes:

```java
private static final Character[] EMPTY_ARRAY_STRING = new Character[0];

public String removeAll(String original, Set<String> remove) {
  Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
  for (char c : original.toCharArray()) {
    if (stack.isEmpty()) {
      stack.push(c);
    }
    else {
      final char t = stack.peek();
      boolean matches = false;
      for(Iterator<String> iterator = remove.iterator(); iterator.hasNext() && !matches; ) {
        String rem = iterator.next();
        matches = (t == rem.charAt(0) && c == rem.charAt(1));
      }
      if (matches) {
        stack.pop();
      }
      else {
        stack.push(c);
      }
    }
  }
  return Arrays.toString(stack.toArray(EMPTY_ARRAY_STRING));
}
```

Comment: *did not give the same results* see [user3386109's comment on order sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911536/looking-for-a-better-performant-string-replace-solution-in-java/74029528#comment130709716_67912075).

Comment: @greybeard I saw that, but: for a performance optimization I would expect in the first place that the behaviour does not change compared to the original function. Nevertheless I included it in the comparison (+ my implementation) because the differences _could_ be irrelevant. Also the stack implementation is only working for 2 characters to remove - and if this is a condition that holds, the code could be optimized further (but also for the other implementations).